# In which processes are enthalpy conserved and in which processes are energy conserved?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

In certain processes, equations are written to conserve energy(in conjunction with the universal law of conservation of energy). But in some processes, enthalpy conservation equations are written.

When are enthalpy conservation equations used?

What additional information and ease of computation does enthalpy conservation offer over energy conservation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dealing with the distinction between the first law applied to a closed system and the first law applied to an open system operating at steady state.  In the former case, you are dealing with conservation of internal energy and, in the latter case, you are dealing with conservation of enthalpy per unit mass.  The reason for the difference is that, in the open system version of the first law, the part of the work done (that required to push material into and out of the control volume) is lumped into the enthalpy.